# How to link log4cplus.a in a shared library?

Tags: c++, log4cplus

I try to create a shared library called "logtest.so" by linking "liblog4cplus.a" that I have compiled with `-fPIC` option on.

Here is "logtest.cpp" (which is simply used for testing purpose by copying from log4cplus website):

```
#include "log4cplus/logger.h"
#include "log4cplus/loggingmacros.h"
#include "log4cplus/configurator.h"


using namespace log4cplus;

void test()
{
    initialize();
    BasicConfigurator config;
    config.configure();
}
```

Here is the command:

```
g++ -shared logtest.cpp -L . -llog4cplus -pthread -o liblogtest.so -lrt -fPIC
```

And here is the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./liblog4cplus.a(configurator.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTVN9log4cplus23ConfigureAndWatchThreadE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./liblog4cplus.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

By calling:

```
nm liblog4cplus.a | grep _ZTVN9log4cplus23ConfigureAndWatchThreadE
```

I get:

```
0000000000000000 V _ZTVN9log4cplus23ConfigureAndWatchThreadE
```

I tried to add `"-Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN"`, but still get the same error message.

I guess there is something to do with linking static library in a shared libary, but I tried all the suggestions and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring log4cplus, use the `--with-pic` option to get a static library with PIC code that can be linked into a SO.

Comment: Thanks! I will recompile my "liblog4cplus.a" with this option.

Comment: @ALGOFE: Let us know if it fixed your issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.